# Jump from assistant editor to the standard one with currently selected view

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6

When in assistant editor with the left side representing a .storyboard file and the right side representing a header or source file I want to leave the assistant editor and go to the standard one with header or source file left opened.

But when I change from the assistant editor to the standard one (even if my cursor was active on the right side) I get the standard editor view with a .storyboard file opened which was on the left.

Is there some keyboard shortcut which achieves that?